# Why my element uses 2 different font-sizes?

Tags: html, css, font-size, bem

I set a font-size as global. That changes when browser's width change(kind of fluid typography). I setted that to body element.

But when size of browser changes, then it changes(font-size). Why? and How can I stop this?

```css
*,
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: calc(16px + .75vw);
}

.container {
  background-color: #d1c6c6;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container__box {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background-color: #8b2be4;
  width: 90vw;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__box">Gridfan Jessica</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `font-size: calc(16px + .75vw);`.  The size of a `vw` is a function of the viewport's width.

Comment: I know but why is this related with em? Isn't it just related with width of browser? And ems are belongs to the element that I gave. I guess

Comment: You have set all of your font-sizes to be _relative_ to the size of the viewport. Therefore your font sizes will change when the viewport size changes. "But when size of browser changes, then it changes(font-size). Why? and How can I stop this?" It changes for the reason I stated. You can stop it by NOT using font-size units that are a function of the viewport size. I don't think I know how to help you beyond that.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I just wanted to know the logic behinf of it . thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when size of browser changes, then it changes(font-size). Why?

Because you used `vw` font size changes when browser size changes.

> How can I stop this?

Use `px` instead. If that's not eye comfortable, Use media query for different font sizes for different screen widths.

Comment: but after that i set font-size: 1.3em;( for example) it still changes when browser shrink or grow. I mean if i set background-color: red; for X class element and  after 10 lines of code I set backgroud-color: blue; for the X class element. It will be blue, right? then why this is not working here.

Comment: Because em is also relative unit. cm, mm, in, pt and pc are examples of absolute units.  <https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html>